# How to reset all data in android app programmatically?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to create a reset button in Settings. When I'll press this button, all data and shared preferences must be deleted like when I press to `Clear data` in `Manage applications` option.

Is there any way to do that?

```
public class Settings extends MainActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
}

 public static void delete(File file, boolean deleteDir) 
 {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    delete(f, true);
                }
            }
            if (deleteDir) {
                file.delete();
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
        }
  }

 public static void clearData(Context context) 
 {
        File files = context.getDir("tmp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        delete(files.getParentFile(), false);
 }

public void OnClickReset(View v)
{
    clearData(this);
}
```

}

Comment: I think you are talking about `FActory Reset` option

Comment: No, it has to be like clear cache of app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you can use method [`Context.getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29). It returns `File` object which refers on internal app directory.

After that you can access to parent directory and delete all content of it.

**EDITED:**

Well, this code works:

File **AppUtils.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.File;

public class AppUtils {    
    public static void delete(File file, boolean deleteDir) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    delete(f, true);
                }
            }

            if (deleteDir) {
                file.delete();
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    public static void clearData(Context context) {
        File files = context.getDir("tmp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        delete(files.getParentFile(), false);
    }
}
```

But I use method `getDir()` instead of `getFilesDir()` because second one may return `null`.

**NOTE:** If you will have opened `SharedPreferences.Editor`, then you won't delete it! Also, opened database or any opened file descriptor may cause same issue.

Comment: Ok, i'm waiting for it

Comment: It does not work, I've called this method in "OnClick" method of button, nothing

Comment: you need to invoke `clearData()`, but I can't see it in your code

Comment: you should `setOnClickListener` to your button, check this snippet: http://ideone.com/xYfk0r

Comment: After that the button "Clear Data" in "Manage applications" became 
inactive and "Data" = 0.00B. I suppose all data was deleted. BUT all shared preferences were not cleared. In practice it doesn't work. Please, help

Comment: I wrote above: NOTE: If you will have opened SharedPreferences.Editor, then you won't delete it! Make sure that you close any `SharedPreference` objects in runtime! I tested this code! It works! Check one more time, and debug your app, but stop spam in the comments =)

Comment: ok, what I need to do to reset all progress which is contained in shared preferences?